# how i can hide Script in specific subDomain in nextjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

in the _document page, i have A Script for chat window and i need to hide the Script in any subDomain ,

example:

`domain.com` >> `allow` the Script ,,,,

`*.domain.com` >> `disallow` the Script

`*.domain.com/*` >> `disallow` the Script

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
const Document = () => {
  return (
    <Html lang="en">
      <Head>
        <script src="//code.jivosite.com/widget/id" async></script> // this is the script
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}
export default Document;
```

Answer (score 1):

I have just resolved this issue by examining the host value to determine whether it is a domain or a subdomain, and then passing the result to the props of the Document.

```
import { Html, Head, Main, NextScript } from 'next/document'
import NextDocument from "next/document"
import { domain } from '@/config/constants';

const Document = ({ isSubDomain }: any) => {

  return (
    <Html lang="en">
      <Head>
        {!isSubDomain && <script src="//code.jivosite.com/widget/id" async></script>}
      </Head>
      <body>
        <Main />
        <NextScript />
      </body>
    </Html>
  )
}

Document.getInitialProps = async (ctx: any) => {
  const initialProps = await NextDocument.getInitialProps(ctx);
  let isSubDomain = ctx?.req?.headers?.host?.replace(`.${domain}`, "") ? true : false
  return { ...initialProps, isSubDomain };
};

export default Document;
```